# Looping ggplots to create animation: increasing speed

Tags: performance, r, animation, ggplot2

I am creating an animation by a script similar to the following

```
require(ggplot2)
require(animation)

data(diamonds)

ani.record(reset=TRUE)
for (i in 1:100){
 rows <- sample(1:nrow(diamonds), i)
 temp.diamond <- diamonds[rows, ]
 qplot.temp <- qplot(carat, price, alpha=1/100, data=temp.diamond)
 print(qplot.temp)
 ani.record()
 dev.off()
}
ani.replay()
```

However, the script takes a long time to finish and gets slower and slower as `i` increases. The slowness seems to be in printing the display and turning it off (though toggling `dev.off()` doesn't seem to affect the speed noticeably).

Is there a way for `ani.record()` to "see" what's being plotted without having to actually plot it on the screen? Are there any other ways to improve the speed of the script?

Comment: Increase in computation time is not surprising, given that your sample size depends on i, which goes from 1 to 100.

Comment: `ggplot2` is slow' maybe you can do the same in base graphics or lattice?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to calculate and store all of the qplots in a list or other data structure instead of printing them during the calculation loop. Then loop through again and print them all - when you're not dealing with computation + printing in the same loop, it should be much faster.